# What transcoding services can people recommend?

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, transcoding

A client of mine needs to accept a bunch of different video files and convert them to FLV. My experience with FFMEG on a previous project has highlighted that there will be some troublesome files.

Depending on the price my client will pay for a professional service.

What are people using and how are you finding the service?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm totally interested in this topic as well, sad to see no answers yet

Answer (score 8):

<biased answer alert> I recommend Zencoder (http://zencoder.com), built by the same folks that built Flix Cloud (http://flixcloud.com). We've put a ton of work into handling troublesome files, and we can support a wider range of input files than anyone out there. We're also the fastest service on the market and have (we think) a very developer-friendly API.

Answer (score 8):

I can't give any recommondations, as I'm searching for a service to implement for many clients myself. However, perhaps I can help anyone else who is also looking.

It seems there are a couple type of services:

- Encoding

  - [Zencoder](http://zencoder.com)
  - [Encoding.com](http://encoding.com)
  - [PandaStream](http://www.pandastream.com)
  - [Ankoder](http://www.ankoder.com)
  - [HeyWatch](http://heywatch.com)
- Encoding, hosting and video players

  - [Ooyala](http://www.ooyala.com/)
  - [Brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com)
  - [23 Video](http://www.23video.com)

In looking at these services, a few things to consider:

- API supported features

  - Progress calls, encoding complete pings, job tracking, output formats
  - XML or JSON or both
  - Authentication techniques (oauth etc)
- Direct client uploads (no proxy to your server)
- Storage of complete video

  - Temp storage, FTP to your server, Amazon S3
  - Availability of direct (if hosted) url for each format
- Encoding formats

  - All HTML 5 formats (mp4 h264, ogg etc)
  - Mobile encoding support (special settings for android)
- Support

  - SLAs?
  - Phone/email/turn over time?
- Cost (many different payment types)

  - Time of video
  - Number & Time of outputs
  - Filesize (input/output)
  - Large volume discounts

Answer (score 1):

encoding.com is pretty good and cheap. I used them for conversion of uploaded user files to FLV.
After that encoding.com can upload files to AWS S3 or to your FTP account with 'ping' request. Should be enough for automation.

Answer (score 1):

In searching for a provider for this, I did extensive testing with the key companies in this arena -- Encoding.com, Zencoder, Ankoder, and Heywatch.

I found Heywatch and Ankoder to be less than recommendable. Encoding.com was my first choice (as a hunch) to begin the search, and their service performed very well and their documentation was adequate.

Zencoder was the clear winner for me and is what we decided to go with. They have exceptional documentation and a clean API. They deal with issues fast whenever their is an problem that occurs. I would recommend them for anyone who is looking for transcoding, and since they are now a part of Brightcove ($$), I only see the service getting stronger.

Note: I am not affiliated with any of these companies and think my response is relatively unbiased.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking at services for this as well,

just found encoding.com from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404322/programmatically-transcode-mpeg-2-videos)

I also have been looking at CDN's becuase I also need to ensure that the videos don't overwhelm my servers, not sure but I thought some of them said full service media including transcoding. if you need a CDN to deliver the video too it may come with transcoding.

Now I'm getting into server stuff, maybe this should topic should move to server fault?

Answer (score 0):

flixcloud.com from the makers of the on2 vp6 codec which is very good quality. i prefer this over encoding.com as they dont charge a monthly fee.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [BitsOnTheRun](http://www.bitsontherun.com), they offer some great service and reasonable prices.

Answer (score 0):

As a cofounder I'm biased, but [Transloadit](http://transloadit.com) also offers clientside integration.